# postgres Database-first approach with Entity framework in ASP.NET MVC 5 Scaffoding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, ef-database-first

I'm new in ASP.NET and I'm discovering Entity Framework and MVC5, can you give me any link or example of a tutorial using **postgres** **database-first** approach please ? I'm searching in the internet and all what I'm finding is the Code-first approach !